# How to create rayshader time-series animation using R?

Tags: r, sentinel2, rayshader

I want to create a timelapse visualization of terrain motion using rayshader packages. I found this web [article](https://labo.obs-mip.fr/multitemp/khumbu-icefall-in-4d/) which gives a useful tip by using Venµs images.

The script which in the article is

```
library(rayshader)
library(abind)
library(raster)
p="./"
fdem=paste0(p,"HMA_DEM8m_MOS_20170716_tile-677_UTM45_filled_crop_Venus.tif")
pimg=paste0(p,"/VIS1C/")

dem=raster(fdem)
elmat=matrix(extract(dem, extent(dem), buffer = 1000),nrow = ncol(dem), ncol = nrow(dem))

files=list.files(path=pimg, pattern="jpg$", full.names=FALSE, recursive=FALSE)

#rotating view  
th=200
k=0
for (x in files) {
    fimg=paste0(pimg,x)
    fout=paste0(p,"/3Drot/",x)
    print(x)
    txt=substr(x, 36, 43)
    k=k+1
    if (k<length(files)/2){
    th=th+0.5
    }else{
    th=th-0.5
    }
    imgr = raster(fimg,band=1)
    imgg = raster(fimg,band=2)
    imgb = raster(fimg,band=3)
    r = t(matrix(extract(imgr, extent(imgr), buffer = 1000),nrow = ncol(imgr), ncol = nrow(imgr)))
    g = t(matrix(extract(imgg, extent(imgr), buffer = 1000),nrow = ncol(imgr), ncol = nrow(imgr)))
    b = t(matrix(extract(imgb, extent(imgr), buffer = 1000),nrow = ncol(imgr), ncol = nrow(imgr)))
    col=abind(r,g,b,along=3)/255
    plot_3d(col, elmat, zscale = 5, fov = 0, theta = th, zoom = 0.7, phi = 45, windowsize = c(1000, 800))
    render_snapshot(fout,clear = TRUE,title_text = txt, title_color = "black",
               title_font = "Arial", gravity = "NorthEast", title_offset = c(0,0))
    }
```

I have all the RGB composites time-series images which are downloaded from sentinel hub by following this [article](http://www.malikarrahiem.com/making-3d-maps-of-sentinel-2-imagery-with-rayshader/) and DEM to display the rayshader animation but don't know where to put in these scripts. I am stuck at understanding how to change the path to implement the time-series animation.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?